# Case Else Partially Running?

Tags: select, vbscript

Below is a function that is part of a longer script. When I run the code the message box from the `Case Else` branch pops up (despite the input being a valid operator), but then doesn't quit the script.

Why does the code jump to the `Case Else` when the operator is valid? And why doesn't the script terminate when it's already in the `Case Else` branch?

```
Function opr_math(opr, first, second)
    Select Case opr
        Case "+"
            total = CInt(first) + CInt(second)
            MsgBox "Your sum: " & total, 0+65, "Sum"
        Case "*"
            total = CInt(first) * CInt(second)
            MsgBox "Your product: " & total, 0+65, "Product"
        Case "-"
            total = CInt(first) - CInt(second)
            MsgBox "Your difference: " & total, 0+65, "Difference"
        Case "/"
            total = CInt(first) / CInt(second)
            MsgBox "Your quotient: " & total, 0+65, "Quotient"
        Case "^"
            total = CInt(first) ^ CInt(second)
            MsgBox "Your exponent product: " & total, 0+65, "Exponential Product"
        Case "fix"
            total = Fix(CInt(first))
            MsgBox "Fixed number of " & first & " is: " & total, 0+65, "Fixed Number"
        Case "abs"
            total = Abs(CInt(first))
            MsgBox "Absolute of " & first & " is: " & total, 0+65, "Absolute Number"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Your operator was either not listed or invalid!", 0+16, "Error!"
            main.Run("C:\Users\JunFan\Desktop\opr.txt")
            WScript.Quit            
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: By the way, the first line of code is not suppose to be indented!

Comment: Oh Yes! Now I know! Second time already! The case else did not run partially! I just have to much error message box that I cannot find which one is it!

Comment: Should've read clearly!

Comment: Case sensitivity? Try `Select case LCase( opr)`.

Comment: Get rid of the main.Run() line and see if it quits...